# nVLC setting options

Tags: .net, vlc, libvlc

I'm using nVLC. It is a .NET wrapper for VLC.
I want to change the caching time for playing UDP streams.

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931517/sout-option-in-nvlc) but it didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
_player = _factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>();
_player.WindowHandle = _PanelPlayer.Handle;
_media = _factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(ConvertAddressToVlc(cameraAddress));
_media.AddOptions(
    new List<string>() {"--network-caching=10"});
_player.Open(_media);
_player.Play();
this.Invalidate();
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

_media.AddOptions(new List() {":network-caching=10"});

Comment: Please consider adding information, why this solves the problem. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this option to that constructor: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/nVLC/blob/21ce49399a67c98fc5ceeb658eddd7280751555b/src/Implementation/MediaPlayerFactory.cs#L86

Though, I'd suggest you move to Vlc.DotNet. nVLC is not maintained anymore and has not been for a long time.

Comment: The last modification of nVLC was on 12 Feb 2018, but I will definitely take a look at it. Thanks
Projects on GitHub are more maintained than other sites.

Comment: True, but that's the only update in the past 5 years.